# Error running swanky suite contract query

Tags: ink

I get this error running swanky contract tx flipper flip -a alice -g 1000000000. I have increased the gas, I have no clue what else to try. Also is there a place to check for { Err: { Module: { index: '7', error: '0x02000000' } } } like this? Thanks

```
2023-02-03 01:14:43        API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: transaction_unstable_submitAndWatch, transaction_unstable_unwatch
✔ Initialising OK
✔ Getting metadata OK
Gas required: 10,000,000,000
Tx result:
{
  dispatchError: { Module: { index: '7', error: '0x02000000' } },
  dispatchInfo: { weight: '1,449,232,000', class: 'Normal', paysFee: 'Yes' },
  events: [
    { phase: [Object], event: [Object], topics: [] },
    { phase: [Object], event: [Object], topics: [] },
    { phase: [Object], event: [Object], topics: [] }
  ],
  internalError: undefined,
  status: {
    Finalized: '0x15e61e58cd413d8a7eaf72c39398a6829b3c793cecaff79ecc4e993a16320a78'
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which node are you running ?

Comment: I am running swanky node

Comment: if your blockchain has updated to use WeightsV2 then polkadot.js.org/apps may not work. you can look at this PR https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/8538.
instead try using the https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/ or https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui

Answer (score 2):

Ideally the client itself would resolve the correct error from the metadata. However, given the raw error code you can look it up manually:

Find the code for the runtime of the node you are running, and in `lib.rs` you can see all the pallets defined in `construct_runtime!`. Count the pallets starting from 0, in this case `7` is the `Contracts` pallet:

https://github.com/AstarNetwork/swanky-node/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L478

Now we need to find the error in `pallet-contracts`. It is `0x02`, which will be the error at position 2. In this case `OutOfGas`:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1d9a139dd96bf5d1583c725bae6fcac5a0805372/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L826

So you can add a few more zeros to that gas amount. I don't know whether swanky supports this but other tools e.g. [`cargo-contract`](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/) will first perform a dry-run which will automatically estimate the amount of gas required, so you are unlikely to get this error.